# Função JavaScript duplicando dados quando carregado dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, funções

Tenho  uma  função  chamada calculadora ao qual a pagina é carregada  dinamicamente várias vezes (sempre que o usuário chama a página calculadora).

Quando carrega a primeira vez é normal, porém quanto mais carrega a página, mais valores se multiplicam.

Ex: primeira vez, se você digita 1 > aparece 1; na segunda vez, se 1 > 11, terceira 1>>>111... é como se a função estivesse se multiplicando

Eu já tentei deletar a declaração do documento mas nada:

```
delete window.main;
delete calculadora;
$("#tool-show").clear();
```

A função é chamada pela seguinte forma:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
       window.main =  new calculadora();
 }) // esse codigo é chamado toda vez que a  pagina carrega dinamicamente
```

Teria alguma maneira de remover a função decalarada do DOM  ? pois aparemente não estou conseguindo fazer isso
**Abaixo segue o  HTML da pagina**

```
  <div class="fix-top2">
  <div class="cctlr">
    <div id="display" class="displo">
        0
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="enters" id="vals" readonly="" style="float:left;width:100%">
    <input type="button" class="btns nbb nbl" id="vtb1" value="1">
    <input type="button" class="btns nbb" id="vtb2" value="2">
    <input type="button" class="btns nbb" id="vtb3" value="3">
    <input type="button" class="btns nbb nbr" id="soma" value="+">

    <input type="button" class="btns nbb nbl" id="vtb4" value="4">
    <input type="button" class="btns nbb" id="vtb5" value="5">
    <input type="button" class="btns nbb" id="vtb6" value="6">
    <input type="button" class="btns nbb nbr" id="sub" value="-">
    <input type="button" class="btns nbb nbl" id="vtb7" value="7">
    <input type="button" class="btns nbb" id="vtb8" value="8">
    <input type="button" class="btns nbb" id="vtb9" value="9">
    <input type="button" class="btns nbb nbr" id="div" value="/">
    <input type="button" class="btns nbb nbl" id="vtb1" value="C">
    <input type="button" class="btns nbb" id="vtb2" value="0">
    <input type="button" class="btns nbb" id="vtb3" value="=">
    <input type="button" class="btns nbb nbr" id="mult" value="*">
    </div>
    </div>
```

**Abaixo segue o  script completo da calculadora**
Caso alguém queira dar uma olhada:

```
function calculadora() {
   parcial = 0;
   operaca = 'some';
   inputs = $("#vals");
   var def = function () {
       if (inputs.val() == "") {
           inputs.val(0);
       }
   }
   var display = $("#display");
   var some = function () {
       def();
       this.parcial = this.parcial + parseFloat(inputs.val());
       display.html(this.parcial)
       cleanInput();
   }
   var menos = function () {
       def();
       this.parcial = this.parcial - parseFloat(inputs.val());
       display.html(this.parcial)
       cleanInput();
   }
   var mutiplica = function () {
       def();
       this.parcial = this.parcial * parseFloat(inputs.val());
       display.html(this.parcial)
       cleanInput();
   }
   var divide = function () {
       def();
       if (inputs.val() == 0 || inputs.val() == "") {
           this.parcial = this.parcial / 1;
       } else {
           this.parcial = this.parcial / parseFloat(inputs.val());
       }
       display.html(this.parcial)
       cleanInput();

   }
   var displayIcnh = function (a) {
       inputs.val(this.inputs.val() + "" + a);
       console.log(event.type + " is fired");
   }
   var cleanInput = function () {
       inputs.val('')
   }
   var EnterExecute = function () {
       if (this.parcial != 0) {
           if (this.operaca == "some") {
               some();
           }
           if (this.operaca == "divide") {
               divide();
           }
           if (this.operaca == "menos") {
               menos();
           }
           if (this.operaca == "mutiplica") {
               mutiplica();
           }
       } else {
           some();
       }
   }
   var CleanOnes = function () {
       var here = this.inputs.val();
       if (here.length > 0) {
           this.inputs.val(here.substring(0, here.length - 1));
       } else {
           display.html("0");
           parcial = 0;
       }
   }
   $("#soma").click(function () {
       this.operaca = 'some';
       some();
   });
   $("#sub").click(function () {
       this.operaca = 'menos';
       menos();
   });
   $("#div").click(function () {
       this.operaca = 'divide';
       divide();
   });
   $("#mult").click(function () {
       this.operaca = 'mutiplica';
       mutiplica();
   });
   window.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
       console.log(event.keyCode);
       if (event.keyCode === 107) {
           event.preventDefault();
           EnterExecute();
           this.operaca = 'some';
       }
       if (event.keyCode === 109 || event.keyCode === 189) {
           event.preventDefault();
           EnterExecute();
           this.operaca = 'menos';
       }
       if (event.keyCode === 56 || event.keyCode === 106) {
           event.preventDefault();
           EnterExecute();
           this.operaca = 'mutiplica';
       }
       if (event.keyCode === 111 || event.keyCode === 193) {
           event.preventDefault();
           EnterExecute();
           this.operaca = 'divide';
       }
       if (event.keyCode === 49 || event.keyCode === 97) {
           displayIcnh("1");
       }
       if (event.keyCode === 50 || event.keyCode === 98) {
           displayIcnh("2");
       }
       if (event.keyCode === 51 || event.keyCode === 99) {
           displayIcnh("3");
       }
       if (event.keyCode === 52 || event.keyCode === 100) {
           displayIcnh("4");
       }
       if (event.keyCode === 53 || event.keyCode === 101) {
           displayIcnh("5");
       }
       if (event.keyCode === 54 || event.keyCode === 102) {
           displayIcnh("6");
       }
       if (event.keyCode === 55 || event.keyCode === 103) {
           displayIcnh("7");
       }
       if (event.keyCode === 56 || event.keyCode === 104) {
           displayIcnh("8");
       }
       if (event.keyCode === 57 || event.keyCode === 105) {
           displayIcnh("9");
       }
       if (event.keyCode === 48 || event.keyCode === 96) {
           displayIcnh("0");
       }
       if (event.keyCode === 13) {
           event.preventDefault();
           EnterExecute();
       }
       if (event.keyCode === 110 || event.keyCode === 46 || event.keyCode === 8) {
           event.preventDefault();
           CleanOnes();
       }
       if (event.keyCode === 194) {
           if (inputs.val() != '') {
               displayIcnh(".");
           }

       }


   }, true);
}
```

Comment: Adiciona o html da sua página na pergunta

Comment: @LeandroAngelo pronto, eu  acho  que possa ser  o   `window.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) ` mas  n estou  consguindo  remove-lo

Comment: Está faltando uma parte do código... veja no final uma `}` sozinha...

Comment: @ÐvÐ sim verdade estava faltando  o  function calculadora()

Comment: Quando a página é recarregada, não volta tudo ao normal?

Comment: @ÐvÐ , a pagina é carregada dimaicamente por um $.post(){} ou  seja ela não da refresh, quando  eu  do f5 ela fica normal, mas  quando  é carregada dinamicamente pela segunda  vez ela começa a dar esse erro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao criar o mesmo objeto mais de 1 vez, ele passa a ter o seu valor duplicado o número de vezes que foi criado. Verificando se ele já existe, não é necessário criá-lo novamente:

```
if (typeof window.main === "undefined") {
    window.main = new calculadora();
}
```

Comment: obrigado, isso  funcionou  corretamente